# how to decide splitting a cluster or not?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

I have given a Cluster. How can i decide splitting the Cluster in two parts is better than the original Cluster?

I have tried  using K-Mean with k = 2  and again stuck.. Is it better to spilt or not to spilt?

EDit: Well i dont get the downvotes... A little explanation would be helpful to improve the question :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literature proposes different metrics, e.g,

- Bayesiqan Information Criterion
- Alaine Information Criterion